# cast object of type 'Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string, sqlconnection, glimpse

I'm following the ASP MVC Tutorial 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started 
The code below is taken from my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = 
    "UserID,UserName,Name,NoOfLogs,timestamps")] User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.loggers.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

My connection String in the web config looks like this:

```
  <connectionStrings><add name="DatabaseConnectionString"    
  connectionString="Server=.;
  database=dolly;uid=dol;pwd=dol;Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=100;Min Pool 
  Size=4;Network Library=dbmssocn;Application Name=dollymvc;" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

However I received the exception (mentioned in the headline) as another part of the system using Glimpse for DB connectivity. 
Is there any workaround for this? A way to cast the glimpse to SQL?
It is an ASP .NET MVC5 application
I see that the question was asked 4 years ago without an approved answer.
Uninstalling Glipmse in not an option 
[Unable to cast object of type 'Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776705/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-glimpse-ado-alternatetype-glimpsedbconnection-to)

Comment: You really haven't provided enough information for us (e.g.: full stack trace, definition of `db`, etc.) My guess however would be that the `Network Library=dbmssocn` is throwing Entity Framework off.

Comment: It appeared that I was able to fix the error in the DB connection as you may see above. However now it is conflicting with Glimpse DB connection and I need to work it around.